# Insert Objects into Word 2010 with metadata

Tags: ms-word, openxml

Please excuse my ignorance on this subject I am very new to this.

I need to be able to insert images and html that contains tabular data into a word document from a Word Addin. This I have managed to do in its most basic form using the InsertFile method. Word converts the html into its native syntax wordprocessingML which is fine.

However, I need to be able to store some metadata with each inserted object so that it can be regenerated externally and replaced in the document when requested by the user. I have been looking at Open XML but can see how or if it is possible with this either.

Please can you point me in the right direction as to how best I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.